# Is there any way to cycle through virtual desktops with the mouse wheel when in "Task View"?

Tags: windows, desktop

What I mean by that is when you have all of the virtual desktops open at the top and can click on whichever one you want to switch to. I was just wondering if it's possible to cycle through them with the mouse wheel instead until getting to the one you want and then clicking it. Also, while we're at it, is there a way to also cycle through them while in "Task View" with a certain key combo? Also, if there is an app out there that allows you to do this I'd gladly take that suggestion too if it comes down to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the mouse wheel, but with the following key combinations you can cycle through them in Task View:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to open Task View
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move focus to the virtual desktop overview on the top
- Arrow keys to move through the different virtual desktops
- <kbd>Space</kbd> to show the windows in a virtual desktop
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the virtual desktop

Alternatively you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+arrow keys to go through the different virtual desktops directly.

Answer (score 0):

Install a utility such as [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/x-mouse-button-control/), which can intercept Windows mouse messages, and translate them into key-presses. You can set an extra mouse button to send <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to open Desktops View; and use the mouse wheel to send <kbd>→</kbd> to cycle forwards or <kbd>←</kbd> to go backwards.

Note that *X-Mouse Button Control* has "Layers", so that you can choose the context where a specific set of translations are performed, e.g., send those codes only when clicking on the Desktop.